# Error when checking input: expected dense_85_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I got keras network trained models. Unfortunantely I can not use predict function on them. Creation of models are:

```
def create_model(self, item_id):
    self.model = Sequential()

    n_cols = self.train_X.shape[1]

    self.model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
    self.model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(Dense(32, activation='sigmoid'))
    self.model.add(Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'))
    self.model.add(Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'))
    self.model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=3)
    self.model.fit(self.train_X, self.train_Y, validation_split=0.2, epochs=30, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])

    self.save_model(item_id)
```

The predict function looks like this

```
def valuate_criteria(self, item_id):
    if self.models[item_id] is not None:
        test_y_predictions = self.models[item_id].predict(self.test_X.to_numpy().shape[1])
        if test_y_predictions[0][1] >= 0.75:
            return True
        return False
```

The data I am feeding it is dataframe thal looks like this

```
     age  destination  sex  transport  criterion  weather
0    2    23           1    29         1          1
```

I am using the same format on data to train and to predict still I got this error:

```
Error when checking input: expected dense_43_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Thank you in advance I have been lost in this for 3 days now.

The train_df is this Item is either 0 or 1 that is what I am trying to predict

```
     age  destination  sex  transport  criterion  weather  item
0    2    23           1    29         1          1         0
```

This is how I get the training data from previous dataframe

```
self.train_X = self.train_df.drop(columns=['item'])
self.train_Y = to_categorical(self.train_df[['item']])
```

Creating and teaching the modles are running the problem is when I use the predict function with data in self.test_X that is:

```
     age  destination  sex  transport  criterion  weather
0    2    23           1    29         1          1
```

UPDATE:
I found a solution using this question [Tensor is not an element of this graph; deploying Keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127344/tensor-is-not-an-element-of-this-graph-deploying-keras-model)

Comment: you should use `self.test_X.to_numpy()`  instead of `self.test_X.to_numpy().shape[1]` with `pridect()`, shouldn't you??

Comment: I tied that and got Tensor Tensor("dense_72/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.But thanks anyway

Comment: Could you post the shapes of `self.train_X`, `self.train_Y` and `self.test_X`, please? Also, does this error appears in the `fit` or the `predict` function?

Comment: I updated it in the question. Please take a look

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I mean what is the result of `self.train_X.shape`, `self.train_Y.shape` and `self.test_X.shape`?

Comment: self.train_X - (556829, 6)
self.train_Y - (556829, 2)
self.test_X - (1, 6)

Sorry for late answer my server went down.